# How to install and use NIMBUZZ! 

Tags: instant-messaging, nimbuzz

I am a very big fan and user of [NIMBUZZ](http://www.nimbuzz.com/en/)!, an IM client. Please tell me how to use it in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather, try adding Nimbuzz to your Chrome browser.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aogjjhoakpgofjogelilmcdleibaennj?hl=en-US

Answer (score 2):

Install WineHQ, it will enable you to install Windows files.

After which, download Nimbuzz.

Comment: Do you mean [wine](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wine)? [WineHQ](http://www.winehq.org/) is just the Wine website.

Answer (score 1):

You can install it with Wine, but it really is not stable.

Answer (score 0):

You can download psi+ from here. So far, this is the best xmpp chat client in linux that supports nimbuzz. It can be customized easily and configured for multiple servers. It's supports multi-ids.
https://launchpad.net/~psi-plus/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

[Roaster Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYAC1.png)

[Chatroom Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adpMr.png)